# 2D Array get number of not null rows

Tags: c#, linq

I'm stuck in a problem.

I have a class :

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{ 
    public string Name;
    public string[][] values;
    public bool[] flag;
}
```

I wish to get count of rows in `values[][]` where row `!=null`

Comment: `where row !=null` which row?

Comment: Looping All rows in values[][].. values[row][0] i.e. ist col check for null can also be done

Comment: Please edit the question to provide more detail (as in the above comment), else this question is likely to get closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you already have:

```
var vm = new CustomerViewModel();
```

And have populated the values array, then..

For a count of non-null rows try:

```
var count = vm.values.Count(i => i != null);
```

Or for all rows where values[row][0] is not null:

```
var count = vm.values.Count(i => i != null && i.Length > 0 && i[0] != null);
```

Comment: I tried :
int count = model[s].values.Count(m => m[0] != null);
it throws exception :<br/>
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: It throws error in both cases : row, and row + 1st col

Comment: That's because the whole row was null in that case - I've updated the code to catch that case. Also, for case where it's non-null, but zero length.